# Issues when trying to format DATE from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to format a date type property on a model before displaying it. This is the code that I am using:

```
// MODEL
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: { type: String, default: 'Vlad'},
    postDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

ArticleSchema.methods.formatTitle = function() {
    var link = this.title.replace(/\s/g, '-');
    return '/article/' + link;
};

ArticleSchema.methods.snapshot = function() {
    var snapshot = this.content.substring(0, 500);
    return snapshot;
};

ArticleSchema.methods.dateString = function() {
    var date = new Date(this.postDate);
    return date.toDateString();
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

And on the client side I try to display the formatted date using:

```
{{ article.dateString }}
```

Still, whenever I load a view that contains this element, I get a 500 error:

```
Cannot call method 'toDateString' of undefined
```

EDIT1: I have no issue embedding {{ article.snapshot }} in my Views, but when it comes to the Date object, I get an error

EDIT2: When logging the dateString method using console.log(article.dateString()) I get the following:

```
Wed Sep 18 2013
```

EDIT3: This is when I get when using the code provided by dankohn. Is it just me, or is it simply running the method two times in a row?

```
this.postdate: Wed Sep 18 2013 23:27:02 GMT+0300 (EEST)
parsed: 1379536022000
date: Wed Sep 18 2013 23:27:02 GMT+0300 (EEST)
toString: Wed Sep 18 2013
Wed Sep 18 2013
this.postdate: undefined
parsed: NaN
date: Invalid Date
toString: Invalid Date
```

Comment: Your Mongoose model instance methods are only available server-side, not on the client.

Comment: Then how come I can use {{ article.snapshot }} in my Handlebars View and get the snapshot?

Comment: ...try Date.now() with parentheses?

Comment: I am not trying to put the current Date and time; I want to pull the Date from mongodb

Comment: @VladZ. were you able to solve this? I am having exactly the same issue while trying to parde dates from MongoDB.

Comment: @ZeMoon I wasn't able to solve this issue back then. I ended up using the format that MongoDB uses by default and parse it on the front-end with a module such as MomentJS.

Comment: @VladZ. That's what I ended up doing also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten this to make perfectly clear where your date stuff is failing:

```
ArticleSchema.methods.dateString = 
  console.log('this.PostDate: ' + this.postDate)
  var parsed = Date.parse(this.postDate)
  console.log('parsed: ' + parsed)
  var date = new Date(parsed);
  console.log('date: ' + date)
  var toString = date.toDateString();
  comsole.log('toString: ' + toString)
  return toString;
};
```

Separately, if this doesn't work for you, I recommend the library [moment](http://momentjs.com/), which is much easier to work with than native Javascript dates.

Comment: This is how I first tried it and it failed. Do you have any idea why it won't work? I mean, I have no issues bringing snapshot to the view, but it simply won't format the MongoDB Date field. Do you think it has something to do with the fact that mongo stores Date objects in the ISO format? I will take a look at that library! Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: Tried it and I don't get a 500 response anymore. But in the view I get the following string: "Invalid Date". So, the method now returns this string :)

Comment: Use console.log to show what this.postDate is, and update your question with it. Also, I recommend using Chrome: Dev Tools: Console to try out what combination of Date commands will parse the input, convert it to a Date object, and then output it in the string format you're looking for.

Comment: I have updated my post (EDIT2) with the console.log() results.

Comment: Check my update! Also, thank you so much for helping me out! :)

Comment: Yes, it is definitely being called twice. I would recommend adding in a bunch more console.log statements, or running with the debugger, to figure out why you're getting the second call. But, I think it's clear that your issues are not actually with the date functions.

Comment: As soon as I figure it out, I will come back and update the post. Still, thank you very much for your time and help! I really appreciate it!